# Linear Dependence

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

Hey everyone, so for this question I take the three row vectors and put them on top of each other putting $A$ on top and $B$ at the bottom. I then proceed to augment the matrix with the zero vector. I row reduce and solve for the variables $a$, and $b$ in terms of $c$. I then get the non-trivial linear relation but the computer says it isn't right. Can anyone help me with what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your relations are dependence relations for the columns of the input matrix, rather than the rows.  To get the right answer, you need to take the transpose of your matrix before augmenting and row-reducing.